# How to know port number in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I downloaded the Jenkins.war file and ran the command java -jar jenkins.war in my war file directory. It started Jenkins on the default port 8080 but now I want to change the Jenkins default port as I am running tomcat on port 8080. I did not found any Jenkins.xml file in my C:/User/Username/.jenkins folder. How to change the default port for Jenkins in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to run Jenkins on another port, just use the following syntax: `java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=<port-number>`

For example, `java -jar jenkins.war -httpPort=9090`

I would suggest you run Jenkins as a service instead of running it using command line. This will ensure Jenkins keeps running when you restart your system.

Note: Regarding *missing* `jenkins.xml` file, i too don't have it in my installation dir. However, if you install Jenkins as a service using the steps provided [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service#InstallingJenkinsasaWindowsservice-InstallJenkinsasaWindowsservice), it will then generate the `jenkins.xml` file. FYI, i am using Jenkins version `2.222.4`

Comment: I have created Jenkins as a service now so how can I check my port number on which it is running as I want to run tomcat on port 8080

Comment: If you have installed Jenkins as a service, you will now be able to see `jenkins.xml` in your installation directory. Check that file to find the port that's currently in use.